# Is there a templating / compiler for sublime text 2 for web development?

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I am trying to find a simple 'compiler' for html templates whereby you can define template files with the updatable parts of those templates defined in {squiggly brackets} or such. Then using a markup language or xml or such, generate flat html in a copiled folder.

Does such a package exist?

It would be great for rattling out multiple language flat html or other 'large batches' of otherwise identical pages with minimal effort.

Comment: as far as i understood, i don't think you are looking for the right thing, or such a thing exists..

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a static site generator like [middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) or [nanoc](http://middlemanapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is not in the scope of Sublime Text 2. Sublime Text 2 is a text editor, not web site generator, so you are asking your question in wrong way.

Instead use standalone product like Pelican http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.1.1/ through Sublime Text 2 build system. Build system offers generic way to integrate command line applications and there is no need to create "plugin" for such use case.

So the answer is

- Learn how to use the command line tool
- Integrate it to Sublime Text 2 building  http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html